# UIScrollView can zoom, but cant pan

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIScrollView with  a `UIView` inside it, in side the `UIView` I made a button to add `textLabels` to it.
and ideally I would want a really big canvas and be able to put text on it and pan and zoom around. however with the `UIScrollView` it does zoom, but does not pan at all

It seems that when I remove the `UIView` that i add inside the `UIScrollView` it works fine.

heres viewDidLoad:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

CGFloat mainViewWidth = 700;
CGFloat mainViewHeight = 500;

//scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height * kNumberOfPages);
//self.mainScrollView.bounds = CGRectMake(0., 0., 3000, 3000);
self.mainScrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
self.mainScrollView.delegate = self;
self.mainScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 50.;
self.mainScrollView.minimumZoomScale = .1;
self.mainScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;


self.mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, mainViewWidth, mainViewHeight)];
[self.mainView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
self.mainView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.82110049709463495
                                                        green:1
                                                        blue:0.95704295882687884
                                                        alpha:1];


[self.mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(5000, 5000)];
[self.mainScrollView insertSubview:self.mainView atIndex:0];
```

Edit:
Heres the all I have for UIScrollViewDelegate

```
#pragma mark - Scroll View Delegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {

}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //
    return self.mainView;
}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)zoomedScrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{

}
```

Comment: Just to make it clearer: why do you set the content size of the scroll view to be so much bigger than the view's size?

Comment: Anyway your code looks ok, maybe the problem lays somewhere else?

Comment: the number is really arbitrary, i just put a really big random number.

Comment: is there anything in the delegate that needs to be set to make scrolling/panning work?

Comment: No the panning should happen without any need for the delegate! Anyway, you can try to explicitly set `self. mainScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;` (even if it should already default to YES)

Comment: i tried and it still doesnt work, the issue is defiantly somewhere else, i put a NSLog line inside scrollViewDidScroll, and nothing showed on the console, ill keep looking

Comment: it seems when i put the UIView inside the scrollview it stops working, without that view, the view scrolls fine.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `setUserInteractionEnabled:` call? That might somehow stop the event propagation for panning...

Comment: yea i tried, i ended up creating a view and putting everything in that view, and it scrolled, didnt change anything...

Answer (score 2):

I just went through this exact same dilemma.

My UIScrollView exists within the storyboard, and if I add a UIView (`containerView`) within that storyboard to the UIScrollView, the image fails to pan.  And all sorts of other centering weirdness occurs too.

But if I do it through code:

```
// Set up the image we want to scroll & zoom
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plan-150ppi.jpg"];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.imageView.frame];
[self.containerView addSubview:self.imageView];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.containerView];

// Tell the scroll view the size of the contents
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.containerView.frame.size;
```

... then it works just fine.